# How to mention ip port in random ip curl script

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a random IP script for curl but i don't know how to use port for same random script

```
function curl_get($kix) 
 {
 $ips = array(
     '85.10.230.132',
     '88.198.242.9',
     '88.198.242.10',
     '88.198.242.11',
     '88.198.242.12',
     '88.198.242.13',
     '88.198.242.14',
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $kix);
  @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ips[rand(0, count($ips)-1)]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $html; 
 }
```

You can see here i have mentioned the ip but i dont know how to mention port for those ip's.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is it a fixed port or a random port ?

Comment: @azarudeen For each `IP`, Do you have different ports?

Comment: Yes, for each ip i have different port

Comment: @funilrys Its a fixed port for each ip

Answer (score 0):

If you have different ports per IP, you can associate the port to the IP with an associative array.

So for the following function I assume that you use PHP >= 7.0 and the following as format of our array.

```
array('IP'=>'Port');
```

We also **CURLOPT_PORT** to assign the alternative IP to connect with. 
To quote the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_PORT:** An alternative port number to connect to.

So back to your issue:

- I use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);` to assign the port we need to use.
- I use `array_rand($ips)` to get a random key from the newly created associative array (The list of IP)
- Finally I get its port with direct access to the array using `$port = $ips[$randomIP];`

So your function now looks like:

```
function curl_get($kix)
{
    $ips = array(
         '85.10.230.132' => '80',
         '88.198.242.9' => '8080',
         '88.198.242.10' => '5754',
         '88.198.242.11' => '80',
         '88.198.242.12' => '8888',
         '88.198.242.13' => '8989',
         '88.198.242.14' => '8080',
      );

    // We get a random key (IP)
    $randomIP = array_rand($ips);

    // We get the port according to the random key (IP)
    $port = $ips[$randomIP];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $kix);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $randomIP);

    // We set the alternative port with the following
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $html;
}
```